# Opening jQueryMobile's dialog with a link to specified jQueryMobile page in different file

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, dialog

I have two files - index.html and c.html.

When I type

```
<a data-rel="dialog" data-transition="flip" href="c.html">button</a>
```

in index.html, it works as it should displaying c.html as a dialog. However using

```
<a data-rel="dialog" data-transition="flip" href="c.html#0">button</a>
```

does not work at all (I wanted it to display the id="0" page in c.html). How to make it work?

Comment: You need to use `<a data-rel="dialog" data-transition="flip" href="c.html/#0">button</a>`

Comment: `id` attributes must begin with a letter.

Comment: @StanCromlish - it does not work.

Comment: @Nelson - this either

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can't be done.

jQuery Mobile does not support query parameter passing to internal/embedded pages but there are two plugins that you can add to your project to support this feature. There is a lightweight page [params plugin](https://github.com/jblas/jquery-mobile-plugins/tree/master/page-params) and a more fully featured [jQuery Mobile router plugin](https://github.com/azicchetti/jquerymobile-router) for use with backbone.js or spine.js. A newer plugin called [routerlite](https://github.com/1Marc/jquery-mobile-routerlite) keeps it simple with just four methods: routeinit, routechange, pageinit and pagechange.

Official documentation: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html

Proof:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
            <a href="index3.html#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

**index3.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="third">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Third Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div> 
    <div data-role="page" id="second">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Second Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#index" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">

        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>    
</body>
</html>
```